# Enable design mode of an sln project in SharpDevelop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, sharpdevelop, designmode

I've been given a folder with many .cs files and a .sln to work on with the express interest of designing a GUI for the entire project. The only problem is, I don't know how.

I have both Visual Studio 2010 and SharpDevelop 4.4 at my disposal; though I'd like to learn both evenly if possible, because I like open-source IDEs, but value experience in Visual Studio as well.

I can't find any information on how to enable design mode in this situation because of how narrow my experience is with the tools; You see, I know to right-click on a .cs file in order to view its code or design in Visual Studio 2010... but that isn't available here. The only item I can see is "view code", which is not what I'm trying to do.

If I can't *enable* the form, I'm wondering if I can just... create a new one? Since one does not exist?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: A screenshot of what I see (blurred for security)[image]

Comment: What sort of file are you trying to design? Windows form?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. The project is as blatant as "Design a GUI for this", but if I had to guess, I would say yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Abstract answer

The designer only makes sense for some types of files. For example, Windows Forms designer exists for classes that inherit `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, and when the relevant attributes for that file are set in the project.

### Practical answer

- Make sure you have a project that allows Forms (like "Windows Forms Application" or "Windows Forms Control Library"), create one if needed.
- In project tree, right-click on the project and use some "add new ..." in the context menu.
- There, choose "Form" or "Control" depending on your intent. It should create and configure what's needed, and you'll be able to use the designer.

In Visual Studio you can switch between text and designer with a shortcut key (F7, Shift-F7) or context menu. In sharpdevelop use the "Source" and "Design" tabs.

Answer (score 2):

In SharpDevelop if there is a designer available for the file then you can open the designer by:

1. Open the file into the text editor.
2. Click the **Design** tab at the bottom of the text editor.

Comment: There is no Design tab at the bottom of the editor-- There is no "Code" tab either. I'm editing my post to include a screenshot of what I'm working with and what I see.

Comment: The screenshot has been added.

Comment: I cannot see the source code but it looks like the a Program.cs file. This does not look like a form so there is not going to be a designer for this file. If the design view is available in Visual Studio I would use that instead.

Comment: I'm confused as to the underlying structure of a visual C# project-- there were two projects, one that I started from scratch. This one already had an extra file that had a designer tab. It also had a program.cs file, which has no designer tab.

Comment: @jwarner112, your confusion comes from how SharpDevelop and Visual Studio differs. A typical Visual C# WinForms